# javascript validation in cakephp says field which isn't required isn't valid

Tags: javascript, php, validation, cakephp

I have a form, one of the inputs of which is:

```
echo $this->Form->input('email', array('class'=>'formInputRegular halfTd notRequired', 'id'=>'email', 'default'=>'Email'));
```

The email field of this particular model isn't required. But when I try to submit the form with that input empty the automatic javascript validation appears asking me to enter something.

There is no rule in the model for this field. It's not required in the database. It may once have been (I don't think so) and I've changed it, but I've since re-baked the code for this particular model/controller so that shouldn't be a problem.

Any one any ideas on why the auto javascript validation is kicking in?

Comment: what does your model validation look like as well as your controller action? Also, have you tried setting 'default' => false?

Comment: @ebadedude There is no validation rule set for email in the model. The model and controller and views were all baked and the field isn't set to not null in the database, so therefore don't get validation rules automatically written. Any other ideas?

Comment: Without seeing code, it will be difficult to point out any mistakes. CakePHP aside, another way to look at it is that there are only two possibilities for why you are getting the validation error, before post or after post. If it is before post, then there is a JS function doing a check on form submit. If it is after, then you can generate a log of $this->request->data to see what is being submitted and check that against what is being validated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it is caused by HTML 5 required attribute. This is a new feature since CakePHP 2.3. Refer to http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#html5-required

You can turn this off by adding

```
'novalidate' => true
```

to the form.